# Get error code from enum : error in swift 4.2

Tags: swift, auth0

I'm using Auth0 and when using biometrics, they are returning an error but the error code is incorrect.

they have a function that returns:

```
return callback(.touchFailed($0!), nil)
```

$0 is a LAError and .touchFailed is declared as

```
public enum CredentialsManagerError: Error {
    case noCredentials
    case noRefreshToken
    case failedRefresh(Error)
    case touchFailed(Error)
}
```

$0._code has a value of -3

but in the callback function the error._code is always equals to 1

How can I retrieved the actual value of -3?

Comment: Could you show more code? How is `callback` called, how is the error retrieved, and how are you looking inside it? Getting the Error out of `.touchFailed` is not trivial; how are you doing it?

Comment: this is the API call credentialsManager.credentials { [weak self] error, credentials in ...
the code from Auth0 that calls the callback is bioAuth.validateBiometric {
                guard $0 == nil else {
                    return callback(.touchFailed($0!), nil)
                }
                self.retrieveCredentials(withScope: scope, callback: callback)
            }
using String(describing: error) in the callback shows the original description of the LAError...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is you're looking at the wrong error object. There are two error objects arriving, the outer error (`.touchFailed`) and an inner error wrapped up inside it. The inner error is the one you want to examine. But you are not examining it!

To see what I mean, look at this done the wrong way and the right way:

```
public enum CredentialsManagerError: Error {
    case noCredentials
    case noRefreshToken
    case failedRefresh(Error)
    case touchFailed(Error)
}

// let's make a `.touchFailed`
let innerError = NSError(domain: "yoho", code: -3, userInfo: nil)
let outerError = CredentialsManagerError.touchFailed(innerError)

// now let's examine them
// first, the wrong way
print(outerError._code) // 1, because it's the outer error
// now, the right way
if case let .touchFailed(what) = outerError {
    print(what._code) // -3 <--!!!!
}
```